# App keeps closing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I am making an app that records and plays audio, but when I try to run it, it closes. Here is my java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private MediaPlayer mp;
public int isPlaying = 0;
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
public int isRecording = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton button = findViewById(R.id.pressbutton);
    button.setOnTouchListener(handleTouch);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);
    mp.setLooping(true);

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile("R.raw.test");

}


        return true;
    }
};

public void play() {
    mp.start();
    Log.d("MediaPlayer", "started");
    isPlaying = 1;
}

public void pause() {
    mp.pause();
    Log.d("MediaPlayer", "paused");
    isPlaying = 0;
}

public void recorder(View v){
    if (isRecording == 0) {
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();
            isRecording = 1;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else if(isRecording == 1){
        recorder.stop();
        isRecording = 0;
    }
}

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. And, to be clear, Android Studio is not giving me any clue to the errors. I had to leave out some part so it would fit in stackoverflow.

Comment: When you report app crashes, you need to include the stack trace and logcat around the crash. If you don't know what the means, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat. Static analysis is great fun for all but things can get done quicker if people are actually able to see the error (and you might just figure it out for yourself).

Comment: please clarify why you're instantiating a class member variable outside of the constructor or the onCreate( ... )? **MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();** i am genuinely curious.

Comment: please also note _Note: Currently, MediaRecorder does not work on the emulator._ for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed you have the proper permissions to record audio on 6.0 +?

I would add this to your Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

and also check prior to recording like this:

```
private void requestRecordAudioPermission() {

        String requiredPermission = Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;

        // If the user previously denied this permission then show a message explaining why
        // this permission is needed
        if (getActivity().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(requiredPermission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This app needs to record audio through the microphone....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            requestPermissions(new String[]{requiredPermission}, 101);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 101 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // This method is called when the  permissions are given
        }

    }
```